# Node JS - can't send data from Postman

Tags: node.js, json, api, authentication, postman

I solved it, it was a problem with req.body empty

==
I trying to test this route but the data I send is not received. I tried Postman and a VC extension, same problem.

I send this data and I expected it to be available in `req.body`

```
{
    "username": "OPK"
}
```

http://prntscr.com/tn722o
And header is set correctly to application/json
http://prntscr.com/tn74on

I do however get this error when I try rest client extension:

> Header name must be a valid HTTP token ["{"]

app.js

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRoute")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

mongoose.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, {
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// app.use(express.json())

app.use("/user", userRouter)

app.listen(process.env.PORT)
```

useRoute.js:

```
const express = require("express")
const router = express.Router()
const userController = require("../controllers/userController")

router.post("/signup", userController.signUp)

module.exports = router
```

userController.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const userModel = require("../models/userModel")
    
exports.signUp = (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password, passwordAgain } = req.body

  return res.status(422).json({ username: username })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to update your Postman to the latest version and install it as a separate application, not as extension for Chrome.

To check if your server method works in general you can send this request via `curl`:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5000/user/signup' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"username": "OPK"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) with Express.js to handle `POST` requests, that is if you're not using express@4.16.0 or greater.

```
npm instal --save body-parser
```

- 

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 
const app = express()
 
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```